# Testing with iOS 6.1 simulator and XCode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode

I've upgraded to XCode 4.6 which uses iOS simulator 6.1.

However, for some reason, I would like to test my app with 6.0 simulator (And also 61.).

I there is way to instruct Xcode to use simulator 6.0 instead of 6.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to install the iOS 6.0 Simulator via Preferences > Downloads > Components:

[image]

And then select the device from the dropdown menu:

[image]

(Selecting "More Simulators..." from this menu will get you to the above Preferences window directly).

And then run using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components