# Why Jdeveloper not listing earlier IOS version?

Tags: xcode, jdeveloper, hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-maf

I am working on a Oracle MAF mobile app and I want to deploy app on IOS 6.1.6, but my JDeveloper lists IOS 7.0 as minimum target version in deployment profile dialogue box. How can I add earlier IOS version to this list.

My deployment device is iPhone 3GS (IOS 6.1.6)

JDeveloper - 12.1.3

Xcode      - 6.3.1

MAC        - 10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your phone `(3GS)` isn't supported for Oracle MAF. 
Here you can view the [Oracle Mobile Application Framework 2.0.1 Certification Matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/documentation/maf201cert-2298202.html)

But you should be able to use the iOS simulator for `iOS 6.X`. 
Have you verified that you have installed the `iOS 6.X simulator in XCode` ( [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039298/testing-with-ios-6-1-simulator-and-xcode-4-6) if needed)?